# How can I write a REST API to receive an SMS via Twilio Number Using ASp.net Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sms, twilio

I am new to Web Api/Rest API concept but I plan to use Visual Studio 2012 MVC4 Web Api. 
How the heck do I create an application to receive a Text/SMS Message via Twilio and send the response back? I have searched several articles here and at Twilio website but none of them give me any insight on how to use MVC4 Web Api. 
Can somebody please help me and show/give some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

All of our Quickstarts are translated to C# that uses the Razor syntax.  You just need to select *C#* from the language drop down at the top of the page.  Here is a direct link to the start of the C# SMS quickstarts:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms

Also, you might want to check out a series of blog posts I wrote a while ago introducing Twilio to .NET developers, including one on using the Twilio .NET helper library in an ASP.NET MVC application:

- [Twilio for .NET Developers - Part 1: Introducing the Twilio Helper
  Libraries](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/01/twilio-for-net-developers-part-1-introducing-the-twilio-helper-libraries.html)
- [Twilio for .NET Developers - Part 2: Adding Twilio
  Helper Libraries to your Project](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/01/twilio-for-net-developers-part-2-adding-twilio-helper-libraries-to-your-project.html)
- [Twilio for .NET Developers -
  Part 3: Using the Twilio REST API Helper Library](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/01/twilio-for-net-developers-part-3-using-the-twilio-rest-api-helper-library.html)
- [Twilio for .NET
  Developers - Part 4: Using the Twilio.TwiML Helper Library](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-4-using-the-twilio-twiml-helper-library.html)
- [Twilio for .NET Developers - Part 5: Twilio Client, MVC and
  WebMatrix Helper Libraries](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-5-twilio-client-mvc-and-webmatrix-helper-libraries.html)
- [Twilio for .NET Developers - Part 6:
  Creating SMS & Voice Application Flows using ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-6-creating-sms-voice-application-flows-using-asp-net-web-forms.html)
- [Twilio for .NET Developers - Part 7: SMS & Voice Application Flows
  using ASP.NET MVC](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-7-sms-voice-application-flows-using-asp-net-mvc.html)

Specifically for info on responding to text message you'll probably be most interested in Parts 1,2,4 & 7.

Lastly, if you hit the Twilio .NET helper library wiki on GitHub there are some code samples there:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/wiki

I'll also point you at a blog post that developer Long Le wrote for our blog that shows how to reply to Twilio requests using ASp.NET Web API since there are a couple of details needed to do that:

http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/building-twilio-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.html

Personally I find it easier just to use a standard ASP.NET MVC Controller, but thats just my personal preference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked the above URL but didnt see any Web Api examples. Maybe I am wrong. Can you please post few example here for me to understand easily. Thank you.

Comment: The last URL shows how to build Twilio apps with Web API:

http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/building-twilio-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.html  

The third code sample specifically show how to generate the TwiML response to response to Twilios request.  In your case since you want to respond to an incoming SMS, your include the <Sms> verb in your response to Twilio.  Does that help?

Comment: It helps. But I am new to REST API (Web API) as well so totally clueless where to start :-( I was hoping I can get some code and I can follow the same. So when a user sms a Twilio number say with a short code what would twilio send us and how do I receive it and process? Does the response to Twilio means Twilio will send the reply back to the user or do we manually need to send sendsms to Twilio to send the reply back to the user? These are some steps that I am not clear. Any pointers?

Comment: It's really surprising how far you can get with a WebAPI Post method that has a single Twilio.Message input parameter. Sadly it doesn't pick up the inbound SID.

Answer (score 12):

I really don't like any of the documentation out there I found pertaining to Web API, so I wanted to answer this question even though it is a tad stale.

Twilio will issue an HTTP request (you can choose GET or POST verb on Twilio site) to an endpoint that you create and your HTTP response, if the body is formed properly, will issue an SMS response back to the user. I show the Twilio configuration screen shot at the bottom here.

I normally only return json from my endpoints, but for Twilio you must return XML. Set up your routing to have an extension mapped routing (this allows you to set up a URL that will return XML for the Twilio request). This is necessary because Twilio doesn't post text/xml in the Accept header. They actually do have an Accept header, but it contains */* but will fail with anything except XML:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithExtension",
            routeTemplate: "xml/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext="xml" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
```

Now install the TwiML nuget package using the package manager console. This will be used for the TwilioResponse class only.

```
Install-Package Twilio.TwiML
```

Add this class if you want to, not required though if you just want to put the params in the controller action method.

```
public class TwilioRequest
{
    public string MessageSid { get; set; }
    public string AccountSid { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

And then your controller action is something like this:

```
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]TwilioRequest request)
    {            
        TwilioResponse tr = new TwilioResponse();

        if (request.Body == "Hello World")
            tr.Message("Hello back!");
        else
            tr.Message("Text 'Hello World' for a friendly message.");

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tr.Element);
    }
```

or this if you don't want to use the TwilioRequest class that I made:

```
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Get(string body)
    {            
        TwilioResponse tr = new TwilioResponse();

        if (body == "Hello World")
            tr.Message("Hello back!");
        else
            tr.Message("Text 'Hello World' for a friendly message.");

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tr.Element);
    }
```

Finally to test it you will need to configure Twilio to do a GET request to your endpoint. This is what that looked like on their site at the time of this posting:

[image]

Notice that the configuration URL has the /xml/controllername pattern in it. You can test this in the browser, postman, or fiddler before hitting it with Twilio though. The response body should look something like this if working correctly:

```
<response>
<message>Hello Back!</message>
</response>
```

Final notes:

Technically you don't even need the TwiML library as it only provides a wrapper class that serializes to XML and you could write your own in a couple minutes. Also I found it useful to open up a port on the firewall that sent http requests from Twilio to my machine directly so that I could debug when Twilio was working properly.

Comment: Thanks for posting Quesi. I am also looking at how to integrate Twilio in a Web Api app. This was helpful. I am finding that `.AddUriPathExtensionMapping` is not available off of XmlFormatter.

Comment: @webworm It is an extension method in the System.Net.Http.Formatting namespace from the System.Web.Http assembly. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatterextensions.adduripathextensionmapping(v=vs.118).aspx). I copied and pasted it from my actual compiling code.

Comment: If you install Twilio.Mvc package then instead of TwilioRequest class you can use Twilio.Mvc.SmsRequest that has more properties(probably everything that Twilio provides). And also you can use [ValidateRequest("your_Twilio_auth_token")] attribute to validate that request is made by Twilio and not by someone else.